# Meteor 1.2.1 Static Content placement

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have just updated to Meteor 1.2.1 and I'm unsure where to put static content. The new structure is:

```
/client/ 
package.json 
/server/
```

In the past this seems to be a relative path from the /public folder, which no longer exists.

I have tried a number of variations and would like some guidance.

HTML

```
<img src="img/testlogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
```

Image location

```
/client/img/testlogo.png
/img/testlogo.png
/public/img/testlogo.png
/client/testlogo/png.
```

Similar issue with fonts etc..

Comment: this still true using 1.2.1

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul Yes, just pulled the latest version to test. hoping to find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image should be in `public` folder like pre 1.2, but you need to have extra `/` before the path like this

```
<img src="/img/testlogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
```

instead of

```
<img src="img/testlogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
```

Comment: That did the trick. Odd that it doesn't come on Meteor create as part of the template. I can't imagine there would be many apps without any static content.

Comment: @Yonkee Agree with you. May be they want it to be a very simple example on `meteor create`. But strangely it is not even mentioned in documentation as well.

Comment: Yes, I searched for a while any the only thing close was the addAssets and addFiles  for the package.json file. Anyway, thanks for your help.